# Is there a way to have all the functionality of SSRS deployed reports, but with locally deployed reports?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, reportviewer

I have been searching for a few days trying to find out if its possible for locally deployed reports (using ReportViewer in VS 2010) to have all the functionality of remotely deployed reports (SSRS) and have not found an answer.

**Details:**
I have a set of 25 reports that are .rdl format and each has a different set of parameters that a user can change to give them different sets of data. My task is to try and get all these reports to be deployed locally along with an existing application rather than using SSRS. After having a search and a bit of a play with ReportViewer in VS 2010  I have found that parameters are handled differently, along with a few other things. Do I need to remake all my existing reports through VS to have the .rdlc format and with that, set up all the different datasources and parameters manually, or is there a more elegant way to have what I had with SSRS but locally?

Any help or links to articles etc. would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you just use SSRS deployed reports?

Comment: @RBarryYoung The company wants to move away from SSRS as they have spent a lot of time and effort supporting clients with this service. So its felt that deploying them locally along with the application will reduce the amount of support needed from us.

Comment: And now you are finding out differently.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Well, I have hit a few issues, but as I said, if there is an elegant way or if there are any utilities out there to help with it then that's different. If we get over this bump then it saves a lot more effort/time in the future.